# Catch2: Test crashes because call encapsulated in REQUIRE_THROWS throws an exception

Tags: c++, catch2

I'm using catch2 as unit test framework. One test case should check if a function call leads to an exception getting thrown, so I basically write

```
REQUIRE_THROWS (class.throwingFun (arg1, arg2));
```

What happens: The function throws and the test crashes. Looking at the call stack I see that the crash happens because of the exception thrown inside the call to my throwing member function. What could go wrong here so that the exception thrown is not caught by REQUIRE_THROWS but crashes the whole test?

Edit: As this is a complex & closed source project, I cannot make up a minimal & reproducible example of this issue. However, maybe someone experienced a similar error and could give an assumption on what could possibly cause such behaviour.

Comment: [mcve] means you ought to provide the code that we can cut and paste and see the failure.  (Getting a copy of Catch2 is easy enough.)  Otherwise, the best I can say is that "it works for me".

Comment: Generally agree – however as this is a relative complex and closed source application, it's not really possible to share the source or make up a minimal example that reproduces the issue. I hoped someone might have had the same problem and would have an idea of what COULD be wrong

Comment: If it's a closed source project, you can try making a minimal example from scratch.

Comment: My speculation is that the function is not actually throwing a C++ exception, despite the claim to the contrary.  Or there is undefined behavior involved.  (I did not downvote.)

Comment: Also a good idea @Eljay, however it was a different thing. I added my own answer below. However thank your for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Found the reason myself – a bit complicated.

The exception in the function under test should be thrown in case it allocates memory – this is a test for realtime-safe functions that are never allowed to call malloc. For a test, the function passed in activated the scope-based malloc checker and then allocated memory. REQUIRE_THROWS allocates memory internally too and for some reasons it triggered itself this way.

This could only be reproduced in a release build, a debug build worked fine, probably due to inlining of the called function into the expanded catch macro which lead the detection to trigger allocations outside the function body.